# не выдаёт предупреждение

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

при добавлении предупреждений ничего не выдаёт, всегда пишет 0. Использую БД SQLite

```
@client.command(aliases = ['warning', 'warn'])
async def __warn(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send (embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Количество предупреждений **{ctx.author}**: **{cursor.execute('SELECT warn FROM users WHERE id = {}'.format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone() or 0} :rage:**"""
        ))
    else:
        await ctx.send (embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Количество предупреждений **{member}**: **{cursor.execute('SELECT warn FROM users WHERE id = {}'.format(member.id)).fetchone() or 0} :rage:**"""
        ))

#выдача

@client.command(aliases = ['gwarn'])
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True )

async def __gwarn(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, amount: int = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send (f'кому давать то?')
    elif amount is None:
        await ctx.send (f'сколько?')
    elif amount < 1:
        await ctx.send (f'это скок?')   
    else:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET warn = warn + {} WHERE id = {}".format(amount, member.id))
        connection.commit()         
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
```

Comment: посмотри что в базе `SELECT warn FROM users WHERE id = {}`

Comment: я не знаю как этоо сделать

Comment: скачай PyCharm, он поможет тебе подключиться к бд и позволит смотреть ее содержимое.

Comment: там пусто, при запуске ничего не меняеться

Comment: а в таблице users есть что нибудь?

Comment: нет. ничего нету

Comment: значит надо создать. UPDATE не будет выполнен потому что ничего нет)